# MySQL / MariaDB pid ended (cannot start mysql) in CentOS

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have had a system with MySQL up and running for years.  I recently accidentally moved all the directories in /var/lib/mysql to /var/lib/mysql/mysql2 and then fixed it and moved them back...  or so I thought.  I cannot get MySQL to start now.  When starting through cPanel I get:

```
Service Error
The “mysql” service failed to start.

Startup Log
Starting MySQL. ERROR!

Log Messages
160102 16:11:42 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/host.suicideprevention.com.pid ended

mysql has failed. Contact your system administrator if the service does not automagically recover.
```

When trying to start it with `mysqld -start` I get:

```
160102 16:13:17 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.0.23-MariaDB) starting as process 3723 ...
160102 16:13:17 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please consult the Knowledge Base to find out how to run mysqld as root!

160102 16:13:17 [ERROR] Aborting

160102 16:13:17 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

The error file created (.err) contains:

```
160102 16:17:15 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table '"mysql"."innodb_index_stats"' in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 33982.
2016-01-02 16:17:15 7f85301f9700  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
160102 16:17:15 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'mysql/innodb_index_stats'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
160102 16:17:15 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table '"mysql"."innodb_table_stats"' in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 33983.
2016-01-02 16:17:15 7f85301f9700  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
160102 16:17:15 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'mysql/innodb_table_stats'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
160102 16:17:15 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-76.0 started; log sequence number 49285133043
160102 16:17:15 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
160102 16:17:15 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
160102 16:17:15 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
160102 16:17:15 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
160102 16:17:15 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
160102 16:17:15 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/host.suicideprevention.com.pid ended
```

I have tried `chown` and `chmod` and nothing is working.  I am in a panic.

Comment: This is not sw development related question. DBAs or sysadmins will be better placed to answer this, than developers.

Comment: This looks fairly serious.  Unfortunately, if you moved the files with the server running, there's only one way to flawlessly recover, and that has to be done using a delicate manual process prior to the server daemon being stopped.  The immediate issue, though, is that files that should be in `/var/lib/mysql/mysql` can't be located.

Comment: Do you have files called user.frm, user.myd, innodb_table_stats.frm, innodb_table_stats.ibd, innodb_index_stats.frm, innodb_index_stats.ibd somewhere on your system, at this point? If so, where? The lettercase of the extensions may vary, but these files, and several others, *should* be in `/var/lib/mysql/mysql` but if they are elsewhere, mention where you found them.  You will need to proceed with extreme caution before moving anything around.

Comment: Also servers.frm, servers.myd, plugin.frm, plugin.myd are probably among the files the log messages indicate aren't found.  Several of them are also likely to have a .myi file of the same base name.

Comment: It seems that in your previous version you have `innodb_file_per_table` activated for `innoDB`...just compare both `.cnf` files on `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`